# A measure of closeness to a discrete set in a metric space

Tags: pr.probability, metric-spaces

Consider a metric space $(M,d)$ and consider a collection of points $X_n := \{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \subset M$. Let 
$$
  N_\epsilon(y;X_n) := | \{ x \in X_n: d(x,y) \le  \epsilon \}|
$$
where the RHS is the cardinality of a set. For a set $Y \subset M$, define
$$
  N_\epsilon(Y;X_n) = \inf_{y \in Y} N_\epsilon(y;X_n)
$$
Does this quantity look familiar, or is related to a more standard object?

Let us say that $M$ is the standard Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution. What can be said about the asymptotic behavior of $ N_{\epsilon_n}(Y;X_n) $, as $n \to \infty$ and possibly $\epsilon_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the map $y \mapsto N_\epsilon(y,X_n)$ is the convolution of the empirical measure of the sample $X_n$ with the indicator function $I_\epsilon$ of the $\epsilon$-ball around $0$. Therefore, if you take for $X_n$ a sample of i.i.d. random variables with law $\mu$, the law of large numbers implies that $N_\epsilon(y,X_n) / n$ converges to $(I_\epsilon * \mu)(y)$.

If furthermore $\mu$ has a smooth density and $\epsilon_n \to 0$ sufficiently slowly (It should be enough that $n \epsilon_n^d \to \infty$), then you will have that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} {N_{\epsilon_n}(y,X_n) \over \epsilon^d n} = \mu(y)\;.
$$

Comment: You are right. This hold for a single point $Y = \{y\}$. But I am more interested in what happens to the infimum over a general set $Y$. Can one obtain conditions on $Y$ (and the possibly the distribution of $\{x_i\}$) so that $N_{\epsilon_n}(Y;X_n)$ grows with $n$?

Comment: The fluctuation field is going to be approximately Gaussian with variance of order $\epsilon^d n$ and correlation length of order $\epsilon$. This suggests that the supremum of the fluctuations over a bounded region of finite volume $V$ will be of order $\sqrt{\epsilon^d n \log(V/\epsilon)}$. So my guess is that if $Y$ is contained in a region of finite volume and $\mu$ is uniformly bounded below on $Y$, then you should still have $N_{\epsilon_n}(Y,X_n) \sim \epsilon^d n \inf_{y\in Y}\mu(y)$, provided that you choose for example $\epsilon_n \sim n^{-\alpha}$ for some $\alpha < 1/d$.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious as how you got your estimate of the supremum of the fluctuations. I am not quite sure what you mean by correlation length; is that the distance between $y$ and $z$ so that $N_\epsilon(y;X_n)$ and $N_\epsilon(z;X_n)$ become roughly independent? Also, for the supremum estimate, I assume you have some discretiztion argument in mind (?) where $(V/\epsilon^d)$ is the size of an $\epsilon$-net for $Y$?

Comment: Yes, in your case $N_\epsilon(x,X_n)$ and $N_\epsilon(y,X_n)$ are independent (not just approximately) if the distance between $x$ and $y$ is more than $2\epsilon$. Roughly speaking, you get the right answer for the supremum by considering your field as consisting of independent Gaussians with the right variance located at the centre of a grid of size of order $\epsilon$. If you want to look it up, this kind of argument is usually referred to as a "chaining argument".

Comment: Thanks. I have seen chaining, but never thought of it in this intuitive sense, thanks for pointing that out. Re independence, I think there is a subtlety here; strictly speaking, they do not seem to be independent if the balls of radius $\epsilon$  around $x$ and $y$  are disjoint. Suppose for example that $N_\epsilon(x,X_n) = k$. Then, this implies that $N_\epsilon(y,X_n) < n - k$, which is a restriction imposed on the distribution of $ N_\epsilon(y,X_n)$ by knowing the value of $N_\epsilon(x,X_n)$.

Comment: You are right, I was actually thinking of the $X_n$ as a Poisson process (which is what they do look like for large $n$), in which case one would have complete independence.